# Worklight hybrid android project stuck on IBM logo?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a hybrid project which creates a default 'Hello Worklight' page which successfully runs on the android emulator... Now i replaced  the default HTMl page with a different page along with its css and javascript folders... I rebuilt the project... It builds without any errors... But when the apps launches in the emulator....the app is just stuck on the IBM logo... I can see no errors in the logcat, that is why i cant figure out whats the problem... Do i need to modify something when i replaced the default HTML age? Help please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply "replace" the contents of index.html with some other content.

The file MUST contain the following:

- Reference to css/main.css in the HEAD
- References to the following in the BODY

  - js/initOptions.js
  - js/main.js
  - js/messages.js

Without these (and especially initOptions.js and main.js), the app will indeed get stuck on the splash because you will fail to load the Worklight framework, so nothing will work...

Instead, you need to ADD to it (additional references, content, etc).
Explain what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: Thats a very informative answer... thanks a lot... But what im trying to accomplish is....i have simply an HTML mobile app...i have to compile and run that on worklight, thats all... is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: You can't simply "take an app" and have it "run on Worklight"; you need to take the specific parts of your app and place them where it is expected for them to be, in Worklight. Add the CSS to main.css, add the JS to main.js, add replace the body tag with the your own's body. Then, preview it in Worklight Console first.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend for you to read the IBM Worklight training materials before attempting "porting" apps; get familiar first.